# Where can I get source code of AVM3?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Where can i download ActionScript Virtual Machine 2 or 3 sources?

Thank you
Eugene

Comment: Do you mean source code? Or sources of information?

Comment: Plus, there is only AVM1 and 2, no 3.

Comment: Actually I want sources of AVM (C++ sources or etc) to have opportunity to parse and execute swf files by my own, and modify that functions.

Comment: So AVM2 runs last Flash Player 10.x code too?

Comment: Do I have a right understanding that AVM is a core of Flash Player, or should I ask for Flash Player source code?

Comment: The Flash Player is a proprietary product - it is not open source.

Comment: So, no way? What about Tamarin, how to make a sample player then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVM is used to run SWF bytecode.  Only the AVM2 has been open sourced, it was used as foundation for the [Mozilla Tamarin project](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/tamarin/).  Its source code is freely available via CVS.

To write a compiler/decompiler for SWF files, you might want to start with the [AVM2 overview](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf) distributed by Adobe.

Comment: I do not need a compiler of as to swf, I need an executer, AVM for swf to run them.

Comment: How to make a Flash Player from Tamarin, sir?

Comment: Read the introduction: > The goal of the "Tamarin" project is to implement a high-performance, open source implementation of the ActionScript™ 3 language, which is based upon and extends ECMAScript 3rd edition (ES3). ActionScript provides many extensions to the ECMAScript language, including packages, namespaces, classes, and optional strict typing of variables. "Tamarin" implements both a high-performance just-in-time compiler and interpreter.

Comment: I believe it *is* what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Open Sources Flash ActionScript VM](http://blogs.adobe.com/billmccoy/2006/11/adobe_open_sour.html):

> Adobe today announced that we have contributed the source code 
>   to the ActionScript Virtual Machine, a key component of Flash Player, 
>   to a new project [**Tamarin**](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/tamarin/) hosted by the Mozilla Foundation, ...

The source code for Tamarin is available via Mercurial at http://hg.mozilla.org/tamarin-central.